# Magento 2: Admin grid Search by keyword bar missing

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

The 'Search by keyword' bar is missing from all the admin grids(order, invoice, products etc).
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Console errors:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @MagePalExtensions done

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: It didn't work.